# access Apache Configuration from Apache Module

Tags: c++, c, apache, apache-modules

I am developing an Apache 2.x module with I/O filters. I need to access to Apache configuration from httpd.conf from my module filters code. I have "The Apache Modules Book, Application Development with Apache" of Nick Kew, but I have not found this topic inside it.

I need to know some Apache configuration values like LimitRequestFieldSize Directive ([Apache Core Features documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestfieldsize)) or others.

How can I do it?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any luck getting to the configuration? I am pretty much in the need of the same thing right now.

Comment: @wilx no, as you can see, nobody replies...

Comment: @logoff this page [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/developer/modguide.html) has some configuration info that might help

Comment: thanks @Dan, but 9 years later I don't even remember what was I doing XD